# Crystal report parameters aren't being prompted

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports

I'm working on upgrading our application to use Crystal Reports 2008. (v12)  Currently, we use Crystal Reports 2008 *for Visual Studio*. (v10.5 <sub>nice naming convention jerks</sub>)

Most of the time, our application supplies report parameters itself, using the id/name/whatever of the object the user is currently looking at.  This is pretty normal.  However, our users also need to be able to fire up reports directly and supply these parameters themselves.  We are using the `CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer` control to display the report.

With v10.5, a parameter selection wizard would appear, and all was well. Note the presence of the InvoiceNumber parameter.

[image: crystal report 10.5 parameters]
<sub>(source: [glompix.com](http://glompix.com/imagedump/cr10.5-params.jpg))</sub>

However, when I run our reports against v12, some parameters aren't showing up.  In this example, it's the InvoiceNumber parameter.

[image: crystal report 12 parameters]
<sub>(source: [glompix.com](http://glompix.com/imagedump/cr12-params.jpg))</sub>

Our report writer says that there is a solution to this which involves changing every report.  I'm unsure of the details.  We have a *lot* of reports, so I was wondering if there is a solution that can be implemented at the time of report invocation.  Is there an option, property, method, or something to have these missing parameters show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the missing value is static you could try assigning the missing parameter values to the reports programmatically. This would save you the time of changing all reports. - Of course assuming that the missing parameters are not always different in each report...
EDIT:
Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question. If you need the missing parameter box to show up and this is an incompatibility issue there might not be other way but to change the reports. I would be curious though what the details are. (I mean what the report writer could change in the report to make it show)

EDIT:
If the problem is caused by the presence of formulas in the report there might be a solution by assigning the missing values to ReportDocument.RecordSelectionFormula property.

Comment: My knowledge of authoring Crystal Reports is limited, but he says the parameters that aren't showing up "aren't a part of the report."  He would have to move every missing parameter into the report... or something.  I'm thinking that this means they are defined in some place that CrystalReportsViewer doesn't expect, at least in this new version.

Comment: I assume he is referring to formulas that are usually evaluated by using the select expert before the report runs. This helps Crystal to eliminate a part of the dataset (like a WHERE clause in a SQL statement). These "parameters" won't show up as parameters because technically they are not.

Comment: Yup, that sounds like what he's doing.  Thanks!